# Javascript change inner html of div that contains php include

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to do a javscript where the div contents changes after a certain amount of time to include the next flash animation but javascript is not accepting my code.  I've tried to escape `<?php include 'flash-2.php'; ?>` with this `<?php include \'flash-2.php\'; ?>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function()  
        {
        var res = "<?php include \'flash-2.php\'; ?>";
        document.getElementById("swfdiv").innerHTML = res;
        }, 
        3000);
</script>
```

Comment: How can you use Server-side include at client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is your best bet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function()  
{
        $.ajax( "example.php" )
    .done(function(res) {
            document.getElementById("swfdiv").innerHTML = res;
    })

}, 
 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP code is executed BEFORE the page is rendered to the user. Always. No exceptions. By the time your JS runs, it will do nothing.

If you want to include something in your page after it's already loaded, you need to look at an asynchronous technology, like AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show output of you PHP file in a DIV, then call your php file through AJAX and then update the innerHTML of the DIV.

For example if you use jQuery then you can do like,

```
$.get( "flash-2.php", function( data ) {
  $("#swfdiv").html(data);    
});
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 setInterval(function()  
 {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: flash-2.php,
        success: function(res){
            if(res)
            {
                document.getElementById("swfdiv").innerHTML = res;
            }
        }
    }), 
    3000);
</script>
```