# Random order for flash files on page using php, ajax, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, flash

I have no experience of Ajax and little experience of java, lots of sql & php experience so I will probably receive lots of comments for this question but here goes.

Ultimately I have 4 flash swf files that needs to be rotated on the website main page randomly.  So I've found a shuffle javascript function online and implemented that.  Now I need to implement this ajax function (from this post [Javascript change inner html of div that conatins php include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141883/javascript-change-inner-html-of-div-that-conatins-php-include)  ) to change the swf files according to the numbers in the array, so if tempArray = 4,3,1,2 then display flash-4.php for 3sec, then change to flash-3.php for 3sec, then change to flash-1.php for 3sec, etc.

I've got the shuffle part working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var input = this;

    for (var i = input.length-1; i >=0; i--) {

        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
        var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];

        input[randomIndex] = input[i];
        input[i] = itemAtIndex;
    }
    return input;
}

var tempArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
tempArray.shuffle();

// and the result is...
alert(tempArray);    
//alert(tempArray[0]);       
</script>
```

I've got the ajax part where it's replacing the content working:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


setInterval(function()  
{
        $.ajax( "flash-2.php" )
        .done(function(res) {
        document.getElementById("swfdiv").innerHTML = res;
    })

}, 
 3000);
</script>
```

But how do I put it together to rotate depending on the array values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
var index = 0;
var tempArray = ...
setInterval(function()  
{
        index = (index + 1) % tempArray.length;
        $.ajax( "flash-" + tempArray[index] + ".php" )
        .done(function(res) {
        document.getElementById("swfdiv").innerHTML = res;
    })
}, 
3000);
```

Comment: Will give it a try and get back to you:)